# traversing through Hierarchy viewer

Tags: android, android-layout, hierarchy

I have a peculiar request.

Currently we see the home screen of the phone . Contains home icon, maybe Browser icon (atleast 4 icon present)

Now i am given a coordinate (x,y) i know that coordinates is the point where user clicked on the screen.

Using that coordinate i need to get the icon/image which was clicked .eg. coordinate x,y is of the Browser image.

Now how to traverse through the hierarchy to get the exact location (i.e Browser image)
the issue..the points can be part of the Full frame view, it is also part of the pane without status bar, it also exists on the relative layout of the last row. It also exists inside the relative layout of the Browser , it also exists inside the Imageview of the Browser.

i hope you understood my scenario.

Now how can i understand which image to be show..i mean the last leaf node to be shown to user which contains the cooridnate. How can i traverse through the Hierarchy and determine where the point is and what to show to the user.

I just want the Browser image view to be shown as the png image to the user (the last leaf node).

Comment: Which user, the application (home screen) user ?

Comment: i want to capture the image around the coordinate . that is my final output. But to get the final image..using the x,y coordinate..i may need to traverse to the end node. as the cooridnates will be there on the root view, then on the pane, then on the lreative layout of the row, then on the Browser layout, also it may be present on the Image view of the Browser. So from all these ares, i need to reach te last node..ie the Image view of the node and crop that image and save it

Comment: is it possible to traverse through to the final node which contains the Image containing the x,y coordinates

Comment: since the coordinates exists in many place..how do i make up which view to save based on teh coordinates...e.g i just have the coordinates with me..i need to know where the user clicked and get that image and save it